# Publish PostGIS raster to geoserver

Tags: postgis, raster, geoserver

I have a database of raster and vector and I want to use them in my webmapping. There is not a problem to publish the vector using geoserver but I can't publish my raster. Is there possibility to publish postgis raster to geoserver?

Comment: You can publish raster in geoserver using these 
ArcGrid - Arc Grid Coverage Format
GeoTIFF - Tagged Image File Format with Geographic information
Gtopo30 - Gtopo30 Coverage Format
ImageMosaic - Image mosaicking plugin
WorldImage - A raster file accompanied by a spatial data file

Comment: So, in other word: I can't plublish raster from postgres/postgis to geoserver because the raster should not in a database?

Answer (score 3):

The imagemosaic-jdbc plugin should be able to read PostGIS rasters, at least the version shipped with GeoServer 2.2.0

Never tried it out, but there is some documentation here:
http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/raster/imagemosaicjdbc.html
http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/coverage/pgraster.html

Comment: @hnahoulder Could you give a feedback for that? It worked?

Comment: in this recent post you can find some hints on a successful application of the plugin: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/62026/how-to-import-geotiff-via-postgis-into-geoserver